# How to open a specific tab based on today's date (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers, date

I've made a 'Google Sheets' with 31 tabs for the dates of the month (1-31)
How do I write a script that makes the spreadsheet open to that days tab?
*e.g. open tab 25 if today is Aug 25th*

I imagine (from a few other scripts I've seen) that it's something like:

```
function onOpen() {
  var date = getDate(now,'d')
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[date]);  
}
```

but I've never used this programming language and have no idea.

*also, the tabs are named 1, 2, 3.. etc if that's any easier to code*.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. getDate function declaration should be included, also it's a good practice to include a brief description of your search efforts made so far to find similar questions on this site. i.e. There we already have a similar questions [How to open sheets to a specific tab based on days of the week?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143370/88163), please read it and edit your question to include if that question help you or if you need help to understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have 31 sheets, named 1 to 31 respectively.

This script works when the spreadsheet is opened by using a simple `onOpen` trigger.

- `new Date()`: gets today's date
- `now.getDate();` is a shorthand way of getting the day of the month. This is a number
- `ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);`: assigns the day number to the sheet name
- `sheet.getRange("A1").activate();`: goes to the specific sheet and to cell A1. The effect is to open the sheet equal to the day of the month.

---

```
function onOpen() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var now = new Date();
  var dayofmonth = now.getDate();
  var sheetname = dayofmonth;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  sheet.getRange("A1").activate();
  return;
  
}
```